# Regex to split minifiyed SVG Path

Tags: javascript, regex

Due to my poor Regex knowledge I can't seem to work this one out.

I have a string and want to split it down into an array of real number strings.

For example `c15.1-5.3.1-.1.1-.2.1` would become `["15.1", "-5.3", ".1", "-.1", ".1", "-.2", ".1"]`

I have the following code which splits on spaces and minus' but doesn't handle the double decimal. Any thoughts?

```
var path = 'c15.1-5.3.1-.1.1-.2.1'
var a = path.slice(1, path.length).split(/(?=[ -])/)
```

> This is the output: ["15.1", "-5.3.1", "-.1.1", "-.2.1"]

Comment: Why -.2.1 ? why not -.2 and .1 ?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, proves why I need this tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.match` instead of `string.split`

```js
var path = 'c15.1-5.3.1-.1.1-.2.1';
console.log(path.match(/-?\d*(\.\d+)?/g).filter(function(n){ return n != '' }));
```

Comment: Reference to what this helped solve: https://github.com/StueyKent/svg-to-createjs-path